# Choosing an Invertible and differential function with two singularities

Tags: calculus, functions, monte-carlo

I want a function $f(x)$ with following properties:

1. maps from $(0, 1)$ to $(0, 1)$.
2. $f(x)$ is one-to-one (invertible).
3. The 1st derivatives $f'(0)$ and $f'(1)$ are $+\infty$
4. The mapping doesn't significantly warp $x$.
   The best case is $f(x) \approx x$, but this won't satisfy other properties
5. $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable.

   Ideally, $f(x), f'(x), f''(x), \ldots$ are all continuous and well defined for $x \in (0, 1)$.
6. both $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are not complicated.

Comment: I really hate logistic function. The gradients for big $x$ are horribly small and my simulation get stuck near big $x$. By the way, what tag should I use for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f(x)={\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x}+1\over 2}$$

whose graph is like this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/28isfuy3zz

also$$f^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}
{1\over 2}-\sqrt{{1\over 4}-4(x^2-x)^2}&,\quad x>{1\over 2}
\\
{1\over 2}+\sqrt{{1\over 4}-4(x^2-x)^2}&,\quad x\le {1\over 2}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What is the inverse? That is definitely an improvement from logistic function. square root is faster than exponential for computers.

Comment: I'll find the inverse in a second :)

Comment: piecewise is generally bad for my use case. But since my function consists of terms like $f^{-1}(x)(1 - f^{-1}(x))$, this can work for me.